# Re-render component once react form submitted in another component

Tags: reactjs

I have React component `index.js` as below,

```
function Manage() {

    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>Management</title>
        </Head>
        <PageTitleWrapper>
          <PageHeader />
        </PageTitleWrapper>
        <DataTable />
      </>
    );
  }
```

`PageHeader` Component contains a form that submits data to the server. and `DataTable` component contains a table that pulls and populates data from the server.

I want to rerender `DataTable` when form is submitted in `PageHeader` component,

How can I achieve same?

Answer (score 0):

you can:
first: initialize a state in pageHeader that has the response of you api call. second:
using a state management system like Mobx, Redux, Context API etc, or using just props drilling to DataTable as props.
third:
when it changes your DataTable component understand and will re-render itself